# How do I make my own String.Split() and Array.Reverse() built-in functions in one user-defined function to reverse a given string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, user-defined-functions

I have tried this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static string reverseWords(string str){
        ArrayList strArr = new ArrayList();
        int start = 0;
        string revStr = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++){ 
            if(str[i] == ' '){               // if there's a space,
                while(start <= str[i - 1]){  // loop thru the iterated values before space
                    strArr.Add(str[start]);  // add them to the ArrayList
                    start++;                 // increment `start` until all iterated values are-
                }                            // stored and also for the next word to loop thru
            }
        }
        for(int j = strArr.Count - 1; j >= 0;  j--){
            revStr += strArr[j] + " ";             // keep appending ArrayList values to the-
        }                                          // string from the last to the first value
        return revStr;
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(reverseWords("Our favorite color is Pink"));
       //Expected output : Pink is color favorite Our 
    }
}
```

And it's giving this error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Please help me understand why this is not working. And also, if there's better way to do this ReverseWord function manually(not using any built-in functions at all).

I'm sorry if this is such a noob question. Any constructive criticism is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "And also, if there's better way to do this ReverseWord function manually(not using any built-in functions at all)." - why are you doing this?

Comment: Apologies aren't necessary, but the best advice one can ever get in your situation is to set a breakpoint and just step through the code until you reach the error, then hover over the variables and see what the values are.

Comment: @Dai, preparing myself for a technical interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little improved version of your code that actually works for what you are willing to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static string reverseWords(string str){
        ArrayList strArr = new ArrayList();
        string currentWordString = string.Empty; 
        string revStr = string.Empty;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++){ 
            if(str[i] == ' '){               // if there's a space,
                strArr.Add(currentWordString); // add the accumulated word to the array
                currentWordString = string.Empty; // reset accumulator to be used in next iteration
            }else {
                currentWordString += str[i]; // accumulate the word
            }
        }
        
        strArr.Add(currentWordString); // add last word to the array
        
        
        for(int j = strArr.Count - 1; j >= 0;  j--){
            revStr += strArr[j] + " ";             // keep appending ArrayList values to the-
        }                                          // string from the last to the first value
        return revStr;
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(reverseWords("Our favorite color is Pink"));
       //Expected output : Pink is color favorite Our 
    }
}
```

I'll let you do the remaining. Like removing the trainling space at the end of the sentence. add seperators other than space (e.g comma, semicolons...)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 "Our favorite color is Pink".Split('\u0020').Reverse().ToList().ForEach(x =>
  {
      Console.WriteLine(x);
  });
```

Comment: You can remove `'\u0020'`, a white space is the default splitter if none is specified.

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
    public static string ReverseCharacters(string str)
    {
        if(str == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
        }

        int lastIndex = str.Length - 1;
        char[] chars = new char[str.Length];

        char temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.Length/2+1; i++)
        {
            // Swap. You could refactor this to its own method if needed
            temp = str[i];
            chars[i] = str[lastIndex - i];
            chars[lastIndex - i] = temp;
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }

    public static string ReverseWords(string str)
    {
        if (str == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        {
            return str;
        }

        string space = " ";
        StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();
        // reverse every characters
        var reversedCharacters = ReverseCharacters(str);
        // split words (space being word separator here)
        var reversedWords = reversedCharacters.Split(space);
        // for every revered word characters, reverse it back one more time and append.

        foreach(var reversedWord in reversedWords)
        {
            reversed.Append(ReverseCharacters(reversedWord)).Append(space);
        }

        // remove last extra space
        reversed = reversed.Remove(reversed.Length - 1, 1);

        return reversed.ToString();
    }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]